# Strange malloc bad access

Tags: c, malloc, exc-bad-access

I got a problem on allocating memory using malloc in Xcode

When I use a smaller Block_size (256) The code has no problem
If I use larger Block_size (65536) the Xcode will stop at "state1[t] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);" and tell me BAD_ACCESS. How to solve this problem?

Thanks

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     // insert code here...
    int **state1;
    int t = 0;
    int Block_size = 65535;
    state1 = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * Block_size);
    printf("%d",Block_size);
    for (t=0 ; t < Block_size-1 ; t++) {
        state1[t] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    }
    printf("end");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first malloc should be

```
state1 = malloc(sizeof(int *) * Block_size);
```

because you allocate an array of *pointers*. On a 64-bit platform this makes a difference!
Some people prefer to write

```
state1 = malloc(sizeof(*state1) * Block_size);
```

to avoid this kind of error.

*Remark:* In C, you need not cast the return value of `malloc()`.